# A somewhat more general Regular Level Set theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

**Notation**: Suppose $\mathbf \Phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is a smooth map, with $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ an open set and $n\geq m$. The Jacobian is denoted by $\mathbf J_{\mathbf \Phi}(\cdot)$. Let $$k=max\left\lbrace \textrm{Rank}\hspace{1pt}{\mathbf J_{\mathbf \Phi}(\mathbf p)}\ \vert\ \mathbf p \in U\right\rbrace$$
be the maximal rank attained by the Jacobian in the domain, so that $k\leq m$.

**Background**: As stated in most books (e.g., Intro to Smooth Manifolds by Lee), the *regular level set* or *preimage theorem* (and in fact, also *Sard's theorem*) talks about regular values, where a regular value $\mathbf q \in \mathbb R^m$ is characterized by the property that everywhere in its preimage under $\mathbf \Phi$, $\mathbf J_{\mathbf \Phi}(\cdot)$ has a constant row-rank equal to $m$, i.e., is surjective.

My claim is that these theorems are also applicable if $k<m$. Just take a point $\tilde {\mathbf p}\in U$ such that $\mathbf J_{\mathbf \Phi}(\tilde {\mathbf p})$ has rank $k$. Now look at $\mathbf J_{\mathbf \Phi}(\tilde {\mathbf p})$ and pick the $ k$ linearly independent rows. Define $\tilde {\mathbf \Phi}:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^{k}$ which retains only these rows. Now $\tilde {\mathbf \Phi}$ has regular values such as $\tilde{\mathbf \Phi} (\tilde {\mathbf p})$ that we can talk about, even though $\mathbf \Phi$ didn't.

**Concern**: Is there a reason why I'm unable to find the above (somewhat more general) form of these theorems? I can think of a few reasons, including (i) they trivially follow from the textbook versions of the theorems, or (ii) I'm missing some subtleties and my argument is wrong.

Comment: Your argument doesn’t work because $\tilde{\Phi}$ and $\Phi$ don’t have the same level sets. Lee talks about the constant rank theorem. You can show using that canonical form that the preimage of a constant rank map is also a submanifold (but preimage of submanifolds is no longer a submanifold… unlike the case for submersions). Regarding Sard’s theorem, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem#Variants) and the referenced article for a variant involving the Hausdorff measure of the set of values in question.

Comment: Thanks. I see that $\mathbf \Phi^{-1}[\mathbf \Phi (\tilde {\mathbf p})] \subseteq \tilde {\mathbf \Phi}^{-1}[\tilde{\mathbf \Phi }(\tilde {\mathbf p})]$. Can we say anything more about the former ($\mathbf \Phi^{-1}[\mathbf \Phi (\tilde {\mathbf p})]$) since the latter is an embedded submanifold?